# How to get the inner loop to trigger one last time after outer loop is complete

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have two lists:

- The first list holds top name information; multiple descriptors per item
- The second list hold variant of the items within the first list; also multiple descriptors per item

The outer (first) list has has three items; `name1`, `name2`, and `name3`. There is also a `source` but I didn't bother changing it in the sample to keep it simple.

The inner (second) list contains the name and source from the outer list, then has its own name and source.

The end results SHOULD be like so:

```
name1 (source1)
===============
* [name1-foo1]: . "description1"
* [name1-foo2]: . "description2"
* [name1-foo3]: . "description3"

subname1 (subsource1)
---------------
* [name1-sub1-bar1]: . "description1"
* [name1-sub1-bar2]: . "description2"
* [name1-sub1-bar3]: . "description3"

subname2 (subsource1)
---------------
* [name1-sub2-bar1]: . "description1"
* [name1-sub2-bar2]: . "description2"
* [name1-sub2-bar3]: . "description3"

...
```

My problem is that my outer loop looks for changes in the `name` and `source` as a trigger for printing headers and moving on to the next thing to print. But since the inner loop is only trigger by a *change*, when the outer loop runs out, it doesn't run the inner loop one last time to get all the sub-items.

```py
import collections

OuterRecord = collections.namedtuple('OuterRecord',
                                     'name, source, thing, level, description')
InnerRecord = collections.namedtuple('InnerRecord',
                                     'name, source, in_name, in_source, thing, level, description')

o = [
    OuterRecord('name1', 'source1', 'name1-foo1', 1, 'description1'),
    OuterRecord('name1', 'source1', 'name1-foo2', 5, 'description2'),
    OuterRecord('name1', 'source1', 'name1-foo3', 10, 'description3'),

    OuterRecord('name2', 'source1', 'name2-foo1', 1, 'description1'),
    OuterRecord('name2', 'source1', 'name2-foo2', 5, 'description2'),
    OuterRecord('name2', 'source1', 'name2-foo3', 10, 'description3'),

    OuterRecord('name3', 'source1', 'name3-foo1', 1, 'description1'),
    OuterRecord('name3', 'source1', 'name3-foo2', 5, 'description2')
]

i = [
    InnerRecord('name1', 'source1', 'subname1', 'subsource1', 'name1-sub1-bar1', 1, 'description1'),
    InnerRecord('name1', 'source1', 'subname1', 'subsource1', 'name1-sub1-bar2', 1, 'description2'),
    InnerRecord('name1', 'source1', 'subname1', 'subsource1', 'name1-sub1-bar3', 1, 'description3'),

    InnerRecord('name1', 'source1', 'subname2', 'subsource1', 'name1-sub2-bar1', 1, 'description1'),
    InnerRecord('name1', 'source1', 'subname2', 'subsource1', 'name1-sub2-bar2', 1, 'description2'),
    InnerRecord('name1', 'source1', 'subname2', 'subsource1', 'name1-sub2-bar3', 1, 'description3'),

    InnerRecord('name2', 'source1', 'subname3', 'subsource1', 'name2-sub3-bar1', 1, 'description1'),
    InnerRecord('name2', 'source1', 'subname3', 'subsource1', 'name2-sub3-bar2', 1, 'description2'),
    InnerRecord('name2', 'source1', 'subname3', 'subsource1', 'name2-sub3-bar2', 1, 'description3'),

    InnerRecord('name3', 'source1', 'subname4', 'subsource1', 'name3-sub4-bar1', 1, 'description1'),
    InnerRecord('name3', 'source1', 'subname4', 'subsource1', 'name3-sub4-bar2', 1, 'description2'),
    InnerRecord('name3', 'source1', 'subname4', 'subsource1', 'name3-sub4-bar2', 1, 'description3'),

    InnerRecord('name3', 'source1', 'subname5', 'subsource1', 'name3-sub5-bar1', 1, 'description1'),
    InnerRecord('name3', 'source1', 'subname5', 'subsource1', 'name3-sub5-bar2', 1, 'description2'),
    InnerRecord('name3', 'source1', 'subname5', 'subsource1', 'name3-sub5-bar3', 1, 'description3'),

    InnerRecord('name3', 'source1', 'subname6', 'subsource1', 'name3-sub6-bar1', 1, 'description1'),
    InnerRecord('name3', 'source1', 'subname6', 'subsource1', 'name3-sub6-bar2', 1, 'description2'),
    InnerRecord('name3', 'source1', 'subname6', 'subsource1', 'name3-sub6-bar3', 1, 'description3'),
]


def loop_over(outer_list, inner_list):
    current_outer_name = None
    current_outer_source = None
    current_inner_name = None
    current_inner_source = None

    for outer in outer_list:
        if current_outer_name is None:
            print('\n{} ({})'.format(outer.name, outer.source))
            print('=' * 15)

            current_outer_name = outer.name
            current_outer_source = outer.source

        if outer.name != current_outer_name or outer.source != current_outer_source:

            for inner in [x for x in inner_list if x.name == current_outer_name and x.source == current_outer_source]:

                if current_inner_name is None:
                    print('\n{} ({})'.format(inner.in_name, inner.in_source))
                    print('-' * 15)
                    current_inner_name = inner.in_name
                    current_inner_source = inner.in_source

                if inner.in_name != current_inner_name or inner.in_source != current_inner_source:
                    print('\n{} ({})'.format(inner.in_name, inner.in_source))
                    print('-' * 15)
                    current_inner_name = inner.in_name
                    current_inner_source = inner.in_source

                print('* [{}]: . "{}"'.format(inner.thing, inner.description))

            print('\n{} ({})'.format(outer.name, outer.source))
            print('=' * 15)
            current_outer_name = outer.name
            current_outer_source = outer.source

        print('* [{}]: . "{}"'.format(outer.thing, outer.description))


loop_over(o, i)
```

So I could just run the inner loop separate one more time once everything is finished, but that smells horrible.

Is there a better way to structure the loops so that it all happens in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One interesting fact with your code is it looks value behind it to detect change. Unfortunately last value has no opportunity to be detected as the loop ends there.

---

Instead use two pointers one for current & one for **next** value in your list. Use condition like this to detect change in next (**lookahead**)

```py
for index, outer in enumerate(outer_list):
    next_outer_source = outer_list[index + 1] if index < len(outer_list) - 1 else None

    show_outer_header = current_outer_name != outer.name or current_outer_source != outer.source
    show_inner_values = next_outer_source is None or outer.name != next_outer_source.name or outer.source != next_outer_source.source
```

---

Here's a cleaned up copy of your function:

```py
def loop_over(outer_list, inner_list):
    current_outer_name = None
    current_outer_source = None
    current_inner_name = None
    current_inner_source = None
    prev_outer_source = None

    for index, outer in enumerate(outer_list):
        next_outer_source = outer_list[index + 1] if index < len(outer_list) - 1 else None
        
        show_outer_header = current_outer_name != outer.name or current_outer_source != outer.source
        show_inner_values = next_outer_source is None or outer.name != next_outer_source.name or outer.source != next_outer_source.source
        
        # print outer header
        if show_outer_header:
            print('\n{} ({})'.format(outer.name, outer.source))
            print('=' * 15)
            current_outer_name, current_outer_source = outer.name, outer.source

        # print outer value
        print('* [{}]: . "{}"'.format(outer.thing, outer.description))

        # print inner values
        if show_inner_values:
            current_outer_name = outer.name
            current_outer_source = outer.source

            for inner in [x for x in inner_list if x.name == current_outer_name and x.source == current_outer_source]:
                if current_inner_name is None:
                    print('\n{} ({})'.format(inner.in_name, inner.in_source))
                    print('-' * 15)
                    current_inner_name = inner.in_name
                    current_inner_source = inner.in_source

                if inner.in_name != current_inner_name or inner.in_source != current_inner_source:
                    print('\n{} ({})'.format(inner.in_name, inner.in_source))
                    print('-' * 15)
                    current_inner_name = inner.in_name
                    current_inner_source = inner.in_source

                print('* [{}]: . "{}"'.format(inner.thing, inner.description))
```

Output:

```sh
name1 (source1)
===============
* [name1-foo1]: . "description1"
* [name1-foo2]: . "description2"
* [name1-foo3]: . "description3"

subname1 (subsource1)
---------------
* [name1-sub1-bar1]: . "description1"
* [name1-sub1-bar2]: . "description2"
* [name1-sub1-bar3]: . "description3"

subname2 (subsource1)
---------------
* [name1-sub2-bar1]: . "description1"
* [name1-sub2-bar2]: . "description2"
* [name1-sub2-bar3]: . "description3"

name2 (source1)
===============
* [name2-foo1]: . "description1"
* [name2-foo2]: . "description2"
* [name2-foo3]: . "description3"

subname3 (subsource1)
---------------
* [name2-sub3-bar1]: . "description1"
* [name2-sub3-bar2]: . "description2"
* [name2-sub3-bar2]: . "description3"

name3 (source1)
===============
* [name3-foo1]: . "description1"
* [name3-foo2]: . "description2"

subname4 (subsource1)
---------------
* [name3-sub4-bar1]: . "description1"
* [name3-sub4-bar2]: . "description2"
* [name3-sub4-bar2]: . "description3"

subname5 (subsource1)
---------------
* [name3-sub5-bar1]: . "description1"
* [name3-sub5-bar2]: . "description2"
* [name3-sub5-bar3]: . "description3"

subname6 (subsource1)
---------------
* [name3-sub6-bar1]: . "description1"
* [name3-sub6-bar2]: . "description2"
* [name3-sub6-bar3]: . "description3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that efficiency isn't really what you're after, given the verbose data structure, so this seems to be a fairly concise and readable way to get what you need:

```
def print_outer_and_inner(outer_recs, inner_recs):
    for name, source in {(o_rec.name, o_rec.source): None for o_rec in outer_recs}:
        print(f'{name} ({source})')
        print('=' * 15)
        for o_rec in outer_recs:
            if o_rec.name == name:
                print(f'* [{o_rec.thing}]: . "{o_rec.description}"')
        print()
        for sub_name, sub_source in {(i_rec.in_name, i_rec.in_source): None for i_rec in inner_recs}:
            print(f'{sub_name} ({sub_source})')
            print('-' * 15)
            for i_rec in inner_recs:
                if i_rec.in_name == sub_name:
                    print(f'* [{i_rec.thing}]: . "{i_rec.description}"')
            print()


print_outer_and_inner(o, i)
```

The main downside being that it loops a number of times over each list, but what it gets you is brevity and, arguably, readability.

Comment: Unfortunately, that function doesn't seem to print correctly. It prints the outer items out of order, and they all show all the 6 subitems in order of 2, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5

Comment: Good point, replaced the `set()` with `{}` dict definition, effectively the same solution but ordered.